# Alternative to ClickOnce for Shell Extension installation

Tags: .net, clickonce

I need to create an installer for an application which needs to include a shell extension. I read the following in a blog.

> ClickOnce is not a panacea for all solutions, for example, if you
>   wanted to install a shell extension or install a component into the
>   GAC, you'd need to create a full MSI project (also supported by Visual
>   Studio). But for a "typical" departmental application that is to be
>   deployed via the intranet, it's a great solution.

Can any one suggests an alternative to ClickOnce installer which supports shell extensions. Basically, I am looking for  a way to update my  dlls/modules whenever a newer version is released.

Answer (score 0):

We solved a similar problem by deploying the application with ClickOnce and bundling an msi file responsible for Shell Extensions registration with it.

The msi file registered shell extensions and wrote a value to registry, the main application could be started only after it verified the value from registry.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [Wybuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/) quite successfully, if you don't mind buying a solution. You might need to manually add the shell extensions in the registry on the Registry tab.

You will also need to create an installer as well. WyBuild only does automatic updates.